# SlideShow de imagens com android

Tags: android, android-fragment

Alguém sabe como fazer um slide show de imagens em um HorizontalScroolView no android? Ou então sabem de alguma biblioteca que faça isso? Preciso fazer um slideshow dentro de um fragment

Comment: Você deve pesquisar por ViewPager:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html Existem bastante bibliotecas para isso, como por exemplo: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Start-Using http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/ Qualquer dúvida posta aqui, que te ajudamos a configurar. abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu uso uma muito boa chamada [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider)

[image]

### Configuração

#### passo 1 1

##### Gradle

```
dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

#### Passo 2

Adicionar as permissões no `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- if you want to load images from the internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

<!-- if you want to load images from a file OR from the internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

#### passo 3

Adicione o Slider em seu layout:

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
/>
```

Esse é um passo a passo básico tirado do próprio [README](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/README.md) do projeto e traduzido, para instruções mais avançadas consulte o mesmo.